# Interchanging offset values in a binary file

Tags: c++

Recently I've been working on some scripts, and today I encountered a little problem, I would like to interchange the values of 2 offsets of a binary file. Like interchanging the value of the position 0x00 with the value of 0x01, I tried with file.seekp(0x00) and then get the value, hold it in a char, and later to insert the value on the position 0x01 I used file.seekp(0x01) and then file.put(char), but the main problem is that it's not modifying the value of 0x01, just adds the char to it.

Is there any way I could modify it's value ?

**before attempting to interchange the first two offsets values** :
[image: before attempting to interchange the first two offsets values]

**after attempting to interchange the first two offsets values** :
[image: after attempting to interchange the first two offsets values]

And basically, what I need is to interchange them, not to add to the second offset the first's value .

The code I used :

```
char c[1];
fstream file(path, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary );
file.seekp(0x00);
c[0] = file.get();
    
file.seekp(0x01); 
c[1] = file.get(); 
file.put(c[0]); 

file.seekp(0x00);
file.put(c[1]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "just adds the char"? Show a [mcve], the contents of the file before, and the contents of the file after.

Comment: Whenever you do a `get` or `put`, it gets or puts the character at the current offset AND advances the offset by 1.  So your first put will be at offset 2.

Answer (score 1):

`c` should be of size 2 and `get`/`put` move the file cursor leading to the issue.
Here is the corrected code:

```
char c[2];
fstream file("test", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);

file.seekp(0x00);
c[0] = file.get();
c[1] = file.get();

file.seekp(0x00);
file.put(c[1]);
file.put(c[0]);
```

Comment: Still, it doesn't interchange the values.

Comment: From this 25 50 it makes this 50 00

Comment: Strange. Are you sure? I just checked and it works well on my machine (on Linux).